# Citations in graduate school applications

Tags: graduate-admissions, citations

One of my graduate school application question asks me to analyze an economic/ social problem and give solutions. For this question, I need to use facts and statistics in my essay. 
In such case, do i need to use citations in the essay? If so, do I need to use footnotes or in-text citations? As for reference page, since this is a grad school application form, there is no separate section for references.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to use facts and statistics in my essay.

You should always indicate the source of your facts and statistics. That means you will need to use citations. Which format to choose? The social sciences typically use [APA, MLA, or Chicago Manual of Style](http://www.lse.ac.uk/socialPolicy/pdf/InformationForCurrentStudents/PhDStyleGuide.pdf). They are very different: MLA uses in-text citations while CMS uses footnotes. Use the one you prefer and be consistent. It helps to make a good first impression, but of course even a perfect mastery of style will not get you accepted. That depends on the quality of your analysis, so focus your efforts on that above all.

Comment: +1  They are looking for evidence of your potential as a scholar.  The best way to do that is to write like a scholar, following the norms of scholarship in your intended field of study.  Scholars cite their sources.